# Django pagination has_previous and has_next methods doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-pagination

I'm using pagination in Django 1.11. But when I use has_next and has_previous it returns false everytime. Don't print anything. I'm sure that there is previous and next pages. In views I'm using TableView which is like ListView. Here is my code:

```
<div class="pagination">
        <span class="step-links">

          {% if customers.has_next %}
            <p>HAS NEXT</p>
          {% endif %}
          {% if customers.has_previous %}
            <p>HAS PREVİOUS</p>
          {% endif %}




        </span>
      </div>
```

**views.py**

```
class TableView(ExportMixin, SingleTableView):
    model = Customer
    table_class = CustomerTable
    template_name = 'admin_pages/user_admin_page.html'
    context_object_name = 'customers'
    paginate_by = 3
```

*I'm using tableview just for export table.

Comment: use `paginator.has_next`.

Comment: Django 1.11... do you mean 4.11? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should work with the `page_obj` object, so:

```
{% if page_obj.has_next %}
  <p>HAS NEXT</p>
{% endif %}
{% if page_obj.has_previous %}
  <p>HAS PREVİOUS</p>
{% endif %}
```

---

> **Note**: [django-1.11](/questions/tagged/django-1.11) is [no longer supported <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/) since **April 2020**, you should consider upgrading the Django version.